# Как сохранить в базу данных массив значений?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

У меня в проекте есть вкладка статистика, необходимо с каждой тренировки добавлять количество слов в минуту в базу данных, для дальнейшего высчитывания среднего значения. Как я могу добавлять по элементно в массив значения:

```
 update(ref(db, 'users/' + user.localId), {       
    averageWordPerMinute: wordsPerMinute, // Вот тут
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Обновление бд');    
})  
    .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
    });
```

Comment: Почему бы для этого не создать таблицу в БД и туда записывать дату и значение. После можно будет легко посчитать функцией `avg()`

Comment: Создавать таблицу в бд достаточно проблематично, тк использую google firebase, под необходимое значение у меня отведена именно строчка

Comment: Не знаю, может ли firebase выполнять в запросе конкатенацию строк, что то вида 'field = field + newData'. Один из вариантов, запросить данные, обновить строку и ее уже записать.